# Converting a column of dates/times to UNIX timestamps

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a simple Excel sheet consisting of two columns, one of which contains dates and times of the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`. The times are in 24-hour format. Moreover, they are UTC.

I want to convert these dates/times to UNIX timestamps. Unfortunately, I don't use Excel much, and it has been some time since I've used it for something of this nature. My first inclination was to do the following:

The dates/times are in column `A`. I inserted two empty columns, now `B` and `C`, and into cell `C1` I inserted the UNIX epoch (`1/1/1970 0:00`). Then, into cell `B1`, I inserted the formula `=(A1-$C$1)*86400`. I've also tried `=(A1-C1)*86400` and `=(A1-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400`. Sadly, all I get is `##############`.

Where have I gone wrong, and how can this be done?

*If it is somehow useful, all dates are coincidentally of the same month and year.*

Comment: I just noticed you have already tried what I answered, which should work.  Anyway you can put your actual dates into a google sheet so I can see why it's failing?

Comment: sometimes excel is crazy, glad it got to working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the 86400, seconds in a day.  Subtract the unix epoch from your date then multiply by 86400.

`=(yourdate - DATE(1970, 1, 1)) * 86400`

In the other direction (what I originally answered, sorry).

`=DATE(1970, 1,1) + (timestamp/86400)`